# How do I compare row values in SQL Query result?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have got SQL sub-query result as follows

```
A B C
1 2 12
1 4 10
1 3 11
2 5 9
2 3 8
4 7 8
4 9 3
```

Now I have to output values in such a manner for each distinct value in Column A and and for the highest value in column B, I have to return the corresponding value in column C

The output will be

```
A B C
1 4 10
2 5 9
4 9 3
```

How can I accomplish this.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: @Pரதீப் I'm using MySQL

Comment: @dsfasdfadf Google : Top 1 per group in `Mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ANSI standard function `row_number()`:

```
select a, b, c
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by b desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential value to each row.  In this case, all rows with the same value of `a` are assigned the same value, with "1" for the largest `b` value.  You want the first, hence the `seqnum = 1`.

MySQL does not support this function.  Instead, just do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.b = (select max(t2.b) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a);
```

If you care about performance, you want an index on `t(a, b)`.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation for the query you have written. Thank you in anticipation

Comment: @dsfasdfadf . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: I wanted to delete the question since this question is duplicate of this question: Select first row in each GROUP BY group? as pointed out by other users already. What I thought was if I unaccept the answer StackOverflow  would allow me  to delete but it would not since there is an answer to my question. Thanks for your great help. Your solution accepts perfectly well.

Comment: I would add to Gordon's answer that in MySQL < 5.6, you better use a LEFT JOIN clause instead of using a subquery with "select max". Constant subquery results are not cached by the database, therefore the WHERE clause will be fully evaluated for every row the WHERE clause will examine, which can significantly impact query performance. You can use [EverSQL SQL Query Optimizer](http://www.eversql.com) to optimize the query automatically (disclaimer: I'm a co-founder at EverSQL and I humbly suggest the usage of our product).

Comment: @TomerSH . . . Even prior to 5.6, MySQL would use an index for the correlated subquery.